# Flask-SQLAlchemy Group By Multiple Aggregates

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to write a query with two levels of group by in Flask-SQLAlchemy which is equivalent to the following SQL code

```
select right_team_id team_id
,sum(score)-sum(deductions) score from (
  select left_team_id, right_team_id
  ,1.0*sum(case when right_win then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) score
  ,1.0*sum(right_deductions)/2 deductions
  from races
  group by left_team_id, right_team_id ) A
group by right_team_id
```

I started with the following for the first group by

```
query = Races.query.group_by(Races.left_team_id, Races.right_team_id)
.add_columns(func.sum(Races.left_deductions).label('deductions')
,func.sum(case([(Races.left_win, 1)], else_ = 0)).label('wins')
,func.count().label('races'))
```

But each record in query is the following `(<flaskapp.races.models.Races object at 0x107c5f358>, 0, 0, 1)`.  How can I run another group by query, including on the aggregate columns at the end?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not having the db, or what the underlying schema is, this is difficult to verify. Plus the original sql query and sqlalchemy query are rather different. But I think approaching this using subqueries will work well.

```
subq = db.session.query(Races.right_team_id.label('right_team_id'),
             (func.sum(case([(Races.right_win, 1)], else_ = 0))/func.count(Races.id)).label('score'),
             (func.sum(right_deductions)/2).label('deductions')).group_by(Races.left_team_id, Races.right_team_id).subquery()

q = db.session.query(Races.right_team_id, func.sum(subq.c.score)-func.sum(subq.c.deductions)).\
join(subq, subq.c.right_team_id==Races.right_team_id).group_by(Races.right_team_id)
```